# Javascript rxjs - do something when last value emitted from observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Following situation: I make two async http calls.

- one for getting a list of names
- another for making something for each name in the list/array

---

For the sake of simplicity: Lets imagine the first call returns me a list of names: 
`['marta', 'edgar', 'david']`.
And the second http call post the names in the database. 
My implementation works fine for this operational requirement. It looks as follows:

```
public deployAllPartners(): void {
    this.isDeploying = true;
    this.getAllPartner().subscribe(shortname => this.adminService.deploySinglePartnerForTesting(shortname).subscribe());
}

private getAllPartner(): Observable<string> {
    return this.partnerService.getPartnersOverview()
        .flatMap((partnerList) => partnerList.partner) <== returns an array
        .map((partner) => partner.shortname);
}
```

#### Problem:

Now what I want is that the boolean `isDeploying` is turning to false when the last name was deployed. Is there any **RxJS Operator** which is triggered when the last shortname is deployed? Maybe something like `finally()` or something along those line?. For completness: The boolean is there for a loading gif in the HTML and the gif is only showing up in the UI when `isDeploying=true` and of course is hidden when the value is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "end" the chain after a source Observable completes you can use `concat` or since RxJS 6.2.0 also the new `endWith` operator as well.

Or if you don't want to append any values and just do some side-effect you can use the `complete` handler in your `subscribe()` call.

```
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concat } from 'rxjs/operators';

from(['a', 'b', 'c'])
  .pipe(
    concat(of('end')),
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: console.log,
    complete: () => console.log('completed'),
  });
```

See live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-tplu6y?file=index.ts

Comment: Hm both of your solutions, do not work on my code. Completed shows up first in the console. The code looks as follows: `public deployAllPartners(): void {
        this.isDeploying = true;
        this.getAllPartner().subscribe({
            next: (shortname) => this.adminService.deploySinglePartnerForTesting(shortname).subscribe(
                    () => console.log(shortname, 'deployment success'),
                    () => console.log(shortname, 'deployment failed'),
                    () => console.log('done')), complete: () => console.log('completed')
        });
    }`

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz demo?

Comment: The problem with my code is: I open up an async thread with the first call and then  I expect that the second call (the deploy partner call) is finished before the next shortname is emitted. But that is not the case. What I need is that the first observable waits for the second one to be executed. I hope my explanation was somewhere understandable.^^ I need maybe something like an eventEmitter

Answer (score 1):

Use finalize for RXJS6:

```
this.getAllPartner().
.pipe(
    finalize(() => this.isDeploying = false)
  )
```

Comment: For a strange reason `this.isDeploying = false` is called first.

Comment: I have used finalize many times in my code and it works perfectly. It should be declared before subscribe like : `pipe(finialze()).subscribe()`. Have you tried this?

Comment: My mistake i used finally. I guess on my rxjs version there is no finialize. Im using version 5.5.2...

Comment: Then just use `finally().subscribe()`

Comment: As stated above, finally does not work either. Finally on my case is triggered at first instead of at last.

Comment: finalize is also called onError

Comment: @RenéWinkler: Yes we need to hide the loading gif on error also.